# How can I associate a large number of phrases into clusters/categories?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, search, hashable

I'm trying to have a directory site that is still organized by categories and subcategories. Let's say there are a total of 150 subcategories.

I would like to have a mySQL db of phrases/keywords (let's say I have 50,000 phrases total, ranging from 1 word to 3 words) that match to those 150 subcategories. Or think of it in terms of tags, but the tags all correspond to one of those 150 subcategories.

Then the user can enter text, and receive a suggestion as to the corresponding category (or a message, "We couldn't associate your search term with a category")

Example: Someone enters the phrase "dog bite" and the Personal Injury Attorney category is suggested.

To add a layer of complexity, would it be possible to incorporate additional logic so that a particular phrase could be associated with multiple categories?

Example: Someone enters "tenant dispute" and two categories are suggested: Landlord Defense Lawyers and Landlord Plaintiffs Lawyers, since it is unknown from that phrase if the person is the landlord or the tenant.

Comment: Don't dismiss this question quickly people, it looks vague at first but I feel it's still a valid question.